# How to find other Excel instances and assign them to an Excel.Application variable

Tags: excel, process, instance, assign, vba

I'm trying to accomplish being able to find other Excel instances and control them using VBA.

Studying other threads this is what I've come up with so far, but for some reason it doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
Dim xl as Excel.Application
Dim objList As Object
Dim objProcess As Object

Set objList = GetObject("winmgmts:")._
   ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='Excel.exe'")
If objList.Count > 1 Then
   For Each objProcess In objList        '
      If objProcess <> Application Then  '
         Set xl = objProcess             ' this is what doesn't work
         Exit For                        '
      End If                             '
   Next                                  '
Else
   Set xl = New Excel.Application
End If

'Do stuff with xl
```

Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong or if this is this even possible?

Comment: What language are you using? VBA? .Net?

Comment: I'm using VBA (tag-edit)

Comment: Are youu looking for a particular file, or you want to acess all instances for some other reason

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code I quickly put together, this worked for me when I had 5 instances of excel open, each with it's own workbook open. The code pops open a message box for all of the open workbooks in all of the instances of excel and displays the workbook name. You should be able to amend this to assign that workbook or instance of Excel to a variable instead.

```
Sub Testing()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook

For Each xlWB In xlApp.Workbooks
    MsgBox xlWB.Name
Next xlWB

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. When the instance in which my macro runs is the first to be found I don't get to see the other instance. What I want is to identify at least one other instance, perform a check in either way to determine whether the found instance isn't the instance I'm running the macro from and then assign that instance to a variable.

Comment: Have you tried the code above exactly as it is without alterations? Create a new excel workbook and create a macro with the above code. Open a number of other instances and run this code. You should find that you get a message box for every open workbook.

Comment: I did. No mather from which instance I run the code, it always finds the same workbooks (in the same, first opened, instance of Excel). It doesn't find the other ones...

Comment: Strange, it works for me unless I'm not understanding your question and comments, perhaps someone else on here can test this.